# App updates in different appstores

Tags: android, google-play, app-update

I uploaded my app in Google Playstore. So, there are other third party appstores(side-loaded) like Appbrain, which automatically pull apps from Google Play store. My queries are:

1. Will my app get updated automatically in those markets, when I update it in Google Playstore? If yes, how long it takes to get updated?
2. I programmatically check my app version every time(I don't want users to use old version) and take user to Google Play store asking to update my app. So, if user downloaded my app from any other store, how to take him to the corresponding one to update the app or is it ok to take him to Google Play Store irrespective of where it is downloaded from?

**Edit:**
After going through documentation, [getInstallerPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) gives package name of installer.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                    .parse("market://details?id="
                                            + appPackageName)));
```

So the above code takes user to my app's screen in GooglePlaystore as `appPackageName` is passed. So, even knowing installer's package name wouldn't help as I can't send user to the same screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. According to the [User FAQ on Appbrain](http://www.appbrain.com/info/faq/user) in the Copyright infringement question:

> AppBrain extracts content from the Android market. ... As soon as Google removes the app from the Android market, it should also be gone from AppBrain in the next 5-7 days.

So the sync time is around 5-7 days. I think other third-party stores should require the same amount of time to sync their store.

2. I think it is a good idea to direct your users to Google Play as it is the up-to-date, official source. Also if you notify your user of the new version, he/she may still choose to dismiss your notification/dialog window and use his/her preferred third-party source to install the update. Anyways if you get the package name for the installer app, you may create an Intent which can be caught by that app. (e.g Samsung Galaxy Apps store should/will handle any URL intent pointing to an app within it: `http://apps.samsung.com/mars/topApps/topAppsDetail.as?productId=000000660227`)

Answer (score -1):

AppBrain only lists your app information (description, screenshots), it does not provide the APK file.

For downloading the app it links directly to the latest version in Google Play.

To update the app description on AppBrain or to add a new app you go here:

http://www.appbrain.com/info/addapp